# Find Execution Path of Where Clause Programatically?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I am using sql server and i am querying based on a date field. For instance if the only record date was 
2014-1-29 then obviously it would use #1.

```
  Select * from Table
  Where 
  #1(date is between now & 90) or
  #2(date is between 90  * 180) or 
  #2(date is between 180 & 360);
```

Is their anyway to find out which part of the where actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
Select 
   date,
   case 
    when date is between now & 90  then 'date is between now & 90'
    when date is between 90  * 180 then 'date is between 90  * 180'
    when date is between 180 & 360 then 'date is between 180 & 360'
end as [which]
from Table
  Where 
  #1(date is between now & 90) or
  #2(date is between 90  * 180) or 
  #2(date is between 180 & 360);
```